# Изменение title и description на определенных страницах DLE

Tags: php, dle

Есть сайт на DLE. Доступ к сайту по FTP есть, а в админку нету, поэтому ищу харкорное решение. Нужно для двух страниц - главной и страницы услуги прописать title и description, чтобы отличались от остального сайте.

В файле engine.php нашел строчки, но при изменении их меняются тексты на всем сайте, а мне нужно именно на двух страницах.

```
$metatags = <<<HTML
<meta charset="{$config['charset']}">
<title>{$metatags['title']}</title>

<meta name="description" content="Быстрые и качественные исследования в круглосуточном режиме работы, диагностика проводятся высококвалифицированными специалистами, профилактика здоровья ">
<meta name="keywords" content="sattimed.kz, диагностика, диагностический центр, МРТ, КТ, УЗИ, саттимед, рентген, радиология, магнитно-резонансная томография, рентгеновский компьютерный томограф">


{$s_meta}{$robots_meta}

<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="{$PHP_SELF}?do=opensearch" title="{$config['home_title']}">
HTML;
```

Если бы был Wordpress, понятно что можно было бы использовать хуки и условия для изменения тегов под конкретную страницу, а в DLE это вообще возможно? Вроде `if ($main_page) { ... }`. Спасибо

Comment: Мне кажется что как вариант, можно попробовать закинуть [adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) на FTP и сделать эти изменения в БД, так как по идее, раз уж у Вас есть доступ к FTP, то Вы можете посмотреть доступы к БД в конфиге.

Comment: А в самой DLE нет никаких условий для таких штук? Вроде if (главная страница) { бла бла бла } elseif (страница услуг { бла бла }

Comment: Не знаток DLE, но думаю что должно быть, стоит поискать [здесь](https://dle-news.ru/extras/online/index.html?startnews.html) и [здесь](https://dle-news.ru/extras/online/index.html?newitem23.html)

Comment: @Лео а что мешает сделать (закостылить, наверное) `if ($main_page) { ... }` на DLE ? В $_SERVER берем URL, разбираем его и сравниваем нужный "алиас", аля `алиас === 'страница_с_услугами' { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

В общем не ахти документация какая-то у DLE. Отыскал  то что нужно. Все по мета-тегам из engine.php удалил, нашел главный макет main.tpl и вставил в нем между тэгами head конструкцию типа

```
[static=uslugi] здесь метатеги для страницы услуг [/static]

[static=about] здесь метатеги для страницы о нас [/static]

[available=main] здесь метатеги для страницы главной [/available]
```

Соотвтественно в static указывается слаг статичной страницы. Работает и это главное)